# keycloak sso with external application

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, identity

we are using keycloak for our application. tech stack spring boot + nextjs + docket.
there is a third-party application we need to establish single sign-on.

use case (flow) is the following: the user is registered in our app (user management is via keycloak) and we need to get access to external app rest endpoints without additional user registration - SSO.

Please suggest how this can be organized via keycloak and what are the best practices.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The other app REST endpoints should be configured as reousrce server and accept access tokens issued by the Keycloak server you use.

If this other app already has its own OIDC Provider, then it will be in a [multi-tenant situation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/multitenancy.html): accept tokens issued by two OPs. As a side note if you are also responsible for writing the new resource server, I maintain [thin wrappers around `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons) which make configuring a multi-tenant resource server just a matter of setting application properties.

Your OAuth2 client(s) will then call this new resource server just as it calls the one you already have.

You'll also be able to send requests on behalf of the user from your current resource server to the additional one by just [setting the Authorization header of the REST request with access token in the security context](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/bearer-tokens.html#_bearer_token_propagation).

Comment: great explanation. Is there a docs/example I can read more details

Comment: See my edits: the [official doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference) is a must read when working with spring-security. My repo contains many resource server [samples](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples) and [tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) (and all are multi-tenant).